# SharePoint 2016 Personalize this Page missing

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, sharepoint-server

In `SharePoint 2016` there is no option to `Personalize this page`, I have created web part page and the permissions are also set for the page but still the option is missing. Any help to get this option would be appreciated.

Comment: What permission does your user have ?

Comment: Personal Permissions:
Manage Personal Views  -  Create, change, and delete personal views of lists, Add/Remove Personal Web Parts  -  Add or remove personal Web Parts on a Web Part Page, Update Personal Web Parts  -  Update Web Parts to display personalized information.

Answer (score 0):

So far the solution is create a web part page in SharePoint 2013 and copy paste the content in the web part page you have created in SharePoint 2016. Worked for me.